# Merging dataframes in pandas on 'date' only merges headers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I am currently trying to merge two dataframes, by their respective date/time column. Information about each of my data sets are below:

```
data1.head(5)
                  DATE     AA           ...        AB    AB2
0  2011-01-01 00:30:00     6135.998518  ...        0.0   80.331500
1  2011-01-01 01:00:00     5711.638352  ...        0.0   74.380500
2  2011-01-01 01:30:00     5455.901902  ...        0.0   82.742500
3  2011-01-01 02:00:00     5130.634418  ...        0.0  102.091667
4  2011-01-01 02:30:00     4854.064390  ...        0.0  113.467667

[5 rows x 30 columns]

data2.head(5)
        DATE            A DEM         A RRP  ...    AA7 RRP AB DEM       AB RRP
0  2006/01/01 00:30:00  8013.27833    19.67  ...    36.00  5657.67500    20.03
1  2006/01/01 01:00:00  7726.89167    18.56  ...    33.00  5460.39500    18.66
2  2006/01/01 01:30:00  7372.85833    19.09  ...    33.01  5766.02500    20.38
3  2006/01/01 02:00:00  7071.83333    17.40  ...    33.02  5503.25167    18.59
4  2006/01/01 02:30:00  6865.44000    17.00  ...    33.00  5214.01500    17.53

[5 rows x 11 columns]
```

My code I am trying is below.

import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

```
data1=pd.read_csv("1.csv")
data2=pd.read_csv("2.csv")

mergeddf = pd.merge(data1[['DATE','AA','AA2','AB']],
                                 data2[['DATE','A RRP']],on='DATE')


mergeddf.to_csv("out.csv",index=False)
```

And this is what my mergeddf looks like:

[image: mergeddf]

So as you can see the code only merges the headers but not the data. As one of my dates start at `2011` and one of my dates start at `2006` I would like to merge them so that they intersect, so that I start getting data only once their dates cross over, how can I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you verify that there are dates from both dataframes that intersect?

Comment: Yes, they both run to 2019

Comment: You are merging on time as well, are you sure you have same times as well as dates?

Comment: Yes, very sure.

Comment: Are the DATE object/string type? They are formatted differently, so if they are, that's probably the issue.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: pd.merge by default is doing inner - which is what you want..... 

So this suggests that the fields need to be trimmed - and have both datatype being the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DATE column is probably of type object, then you cannot join on differently formatted dates (e.g. 2006/01/01 vs 2006-01-01). You need to change these to type datetime.

```
data1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['DATE'])
data2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['DATE'])

mergeddf = pd.merge(data1[['DATE','AA','AA2','AB']],
                                 data2[['DATE','A RRP']],on='DATE')
```